# How can I set up a gmail notification that will loop a sound until I've read the e-mail?

Tags: java, notifications, gmail

I know this probably sounds really simple, but I've been searching for something that will do this and I have come up with nothing.

**What I Need**

I need something that will notify me of a new e-mail, but *keep playing* a sound until I've read the e-mail. Long story short, we get online orders sent to our e-mail at work, and when we are busy, we might miss the initial notification. I need a sound to play repeatedly until one of us has read the e-mail.

**What I've Found**

I *have* searched, and I have found many ways to get notifications of a new e-mail. The problem is, however, that they only play a sound once. I thought, "No big deal, just make a really long sound file." The problem with that is that none of these programs *stop* the sound once I've checked the e-mail. I might hear the sound right away and receive the order, or I might not be able to check it for 5 minutes. Listening to 5 minutes of dinging while preparing an order will drive us all insane.

**Does Something Exist?**

Does anybody know of any programs that already exist that will do what I need?

**Does Nothing Exist?**

No way to do this in a program that's already out there? *sigh*

In that case, what is the *easiest* API to access gmail from a client computer (and easy to build GUI)? (I'm not getting paid to make this, but it will make life easier for me, so why not?) I am most comfortable working in Java, but I only need to make a program that says, "hey you have new e-mail, let me play you the song of my people until you pay attention to me." Then, once I do something, it marks the e-mail as read. So, whatever language is easiest to do this in will work.

Thank you all so much in advance for any input you may have.

Comment: You might want to look into browser extensions such as GreasyMonkey (Firefox) or TamperMonkey (Chrome). They contain a number of enhancements for gmail, so it's possible that you can extend one of those.

Comment: connect to google via official pop3 or smtp, load the mail and play an sound loop?

Comment: Henrik, I will look into *Monkey extensions, that may just be the easiest thing.

Comment: Dan, yes, current notification programs do that, but they don't stop the looping, I'm just looking for a really easy solution that doesn't involve me programming a whole application. Thanks for the input though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a small Application that talks to gmail using IMAP.  This should allow you to get the events that the mail has arrived and later when it is read.

Then combine that with a sound playing loop.

Note: I have not tried and do not know how fast the events are supplied after the action is taken.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that one of the [mozilla thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) plugins does what you want:

eg:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/?src=search
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tonequilla/?src=search
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/soundplus/?src=search

For instance the [mailbox-alert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/?src=search) plugin allows you to execute any command you like when an email arrives.

Or, you might [write your own extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension)